# MVC FormsCollection

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In .Net Terminology, 'FormCollection' means 'Collection' of 'Forms'
'System.Windows.Forms.FormCollection' is collection of System.Windows.Forms.Form

In ASP.Net MVC, 'FormCollection' is little confusing.

Is it Collection of all Submit 'Forms' in webpage ?

(Or) Is it Collection of Input controls on paritcular form ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a collection of all input values specified in a POST request (which is probably all input values in a **single** form).

Similarly, `QueryStringCollection` holds all input values specified in a GET request.